# Add custom objects with reduce()

Tags: python, functools

I'm trying to add the values of a field from a list of custom objects, but I can't find the solution with `reduce()` function in Python:

```
final_time = init_time + reduce(lambda x, y: x.time_coef + y.time_coef, list_of_paths)
```

The iterable is a list of custom objects (`shapely.LineString`) with a custom field (`time_coef`).

As I understand, `reduce` can do the first addition, but the second iteration fails because it tries to get the `.time_coef` attribute to the result of the previous addition (a float).

Is there any way to avoid this, or should I iterate the list and not use reduce?

Comment: Generally speaking: `reduce(lambda a, i: a + i.time_coef, lst, 0)` — Initialise the accumulator so it's *always* the type returned by the callback.

Comment: thanks @deceze, this is that I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general pattern here is to *initialise* the accumulator with the base value of the type your callback will return, so the first call to the reduce function will not implicitly pass two of your objects:

```
reduce(lambda a, i: a + i.time_coef, lst, 0)
#             initialise your accumulator ^
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sum` with list comprehension

```
final_time = init_time + sum(x.time_coef for x in list_of_paths)
```